# How do you accelerate a molecular structure with EM wave pulses without heating it up?

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics, molecules, molecular-dynamics

vibrating the atom good| heat bad|fast-moving vehicle bad| one-meter cube with different atoms trying to accelerate its whole molecular structure with EM wave pulses but not cause heating damage

Comment: How do porcupines mate? Very carefully. In physics we often call this an "adiabatic process" and it usually means choosing a time scale that is much longer than the internal  timescales. Since molecules are vibrating at really high frequencies this is not particularly hard.